# Getting both Rows and Columns from a Matrix

Tags: data-structures, linear-algebra

Is there a way to get both rows and columns
from a matrix (2D) array in O(1) time?

Obviously, to get one or the other, its trivial to just return the array.
Is there an easy way to get both in O(1) time?

I'm thinking I could have a second matrix, but that would double
my space requirements.

edit:

I could build "columns" but would take O(n) time assuming a n by n matrix. Because, by default, the matrix is an array of arrays. My question is, more concretely, is there a way to change my matrix data structure so that I can do both operations in O(1) time?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "getting", if you allow returning a vector with a stride for example that's pretty simple

Comment: @harold I simply mean returning a vector of a row or a column. But, we must be able to return both (in O(1) time). Trying to do this in Java.

Comment: I could build "columns" but would take O(n) time assuming a n by n matrix. Beause, by default, the matrix is an array of arrays. My question is, more concretely, is there an easy way to change my matrix data structure to do both operations in O(1) time?

Comment: Just store it as a single array where you calculate the x- and y-coordinates from that array.  I.E. index `j` is row `j%n` and column `Int(j/n)`.  If you haven't stored it this way, then no you cannot change it to this way in O(1) time: you have to loop through each row or column to change it.

Comment: You could store the matrix twice, once normally and once transposed (array of columns). Or you could make elements in the matrix also contain pointers to the element below. Then `a[0][j].ptr`would return a pointer to the `j`-th column. But, as the other people have asked, do you actually need a concrete data structure that holds a column and only a column? Couldn't you manipulate matrix indices instead?